# Export Active Directory Users to Excel Using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a script that exports users of each AD group to Excel. In Excel, I will have one workbook, but each group will have a separate sheet. However, I cant seem to get the script to work correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
 ''''
        $A = "group A"
        $B = "group B"
        $C = "group C"
        $D = "group D"
        $E = "182"
        $F = "182Basic3"
        $G =  "A182Robots"
        $H = "501"
        $I = "601"
        $J = "765"
        $K = "S8808"

        $groups = "$A", "$B", "$C", "$D", "$E", "$F", "$G", "$I", "$J", "$K"

        $fileName = "C:\users\rqw82758\Desktop\GroupMemberShip.xlsx"

        foreach ($group in $groups) {
           Get-ADGroupMember $group | select samaccountname, name, @{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}}



        $A| Export-Excel $filename -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A136 Basic"
        $B| Export-excel $filename -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A151 Basic"
        $C| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A154 Basic"
        $D| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A182 Basic"
        $E| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A182 Basic2"
        $F| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A182 Basic3"
        $G| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A182 Robots"
        $H| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A501 Basic"
        $I| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A601 Basic"
        $J| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "A765 Basic"
        $K| Export-excel $fileName -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName "S8808 Basic"

        }
```

''''

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you try to export to Excel **all** groupnames you have in your variables in each iteration, while you are only retrieving info for one single name in each iteration.
Also, I wouldn't try this using all those variables, but instead use a lookup table that holds both the group name as well as the sheet name for Excel.

```
# create a lookup Hashtable with the group names as key and the desired Excel sheet name as value
$lookup   = @{
    'group A'    = 'A136 Basic'
    'group B'    = 'A151 Basic'
    'group C'    = 'A154 Basic'
    'group D'    = 'A182 Basic'
    '182'        = 'A182 Basic2'
    '182Basic3'  = 'A182 Basic3'
    'A182Robots' = 'A182 Robots'
    '501'        = 'A501 Basic'
    '601'        = 'A601 Basic'
    '765'        = 'A765 Basic'
    'S8808'      = 'S8808 Basic'
}
$fileName = 'C:\users\rqw82758\Desktop\GroupMemberShip.xlsx'

foreach ($group in $lookup.Keys) {
    $result = Get-ADGroupMember -Filter "Name -eq '$group'"
    if ($result) {
        $result | Select-Object SamAccountname, Name, @{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}} | 
                  Export-Excel $filename -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName $lookup[$group]
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find a group called '$group'.."
    }
}
```

P.S. perhaps also property `objectClass` might be of interest, because `Get-ADGroupMember` can return objects of type 'user', 'group' and 'computer'

Answer (score 0):

**this is what you miss**

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {
       
       Get-ADGroupMember $group | select samaccountname, name, @{n='GroupName';e={$group}}, @{n='Description';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}}`
       |Export-Excel $filename -Autosize -AutoFilter -Append -WorksheetName $group
              
      }
```